# Plot multiple distributions in Seaborn histogram

Tags: python, plot, seaborn, histogram

I have a dataframe `df_sz` with four columns, and I would like to plot the histogram of each column in a "side-by-side" fashion in Seaborn, i.e., with no overlapping between histograms. However, when I run the following script it overlaps the histograms:

`sns.histplot(data=df_sz, bins=50, alpha=0.5, shrink=0.8, log_scale=True, multiple='layer')`

I have tried with all the options for the `multiple` argument but none of them works.

Any solution? I really need to use Seaborn for this plot.
I have attached a screenshot of the dataframe  and the resulting histogram
[image: dataframe] [image: histogram].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `multiple=` parameter seems to go together with the `hue=` parameter. For this to work, the dataframe should be converted to [long form](http://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/data_structure.html#long-form-vs-wide-form-data):

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df_sz = pd.DataFrame({'Ann1': (2 ** np.random.uniform(1, 20, 200)).astype(int),
                      'Ann2': (2 ** np.random.uniform(1, 20, 200)).astype(int),
                      'Ann3': (2 ** np.random.uniform(1, 20, 200)).astype(int),
                      'Ann4': (2 ** np.random.uniform(1, 20, 200)).astype(int)})

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 4)) # very wide figure to accomodate 200 bars
sns.histplot(data=df_sz.melt(), x='value', hue='variable', bins=50,
             alpha=0.5, shrink=0.8, log_scale=True, multiple='dodge', ax=ax)
ax.legend_.set_title('') # remove the legend title (the name of the hue column)
ax.margins(x=0.01) # less spacing
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.histplot with multiple='dodge' using long form df]

Comment: I don't think the melt is necessary here. All the hue logic (and features) are used with wide-form data, it's just implicit.

Comment: @mwaskom  Thanks. I just tested with the dev version, where the wide form works fine.  In the current 0.11.1 the long form seems to be necessary.

Comment: Oops yes I guess that would be [this bug](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/pull/2462/).